# Ошибка при попытке установить менеджер плагинов Vim

Tags: vim

После выполнения этой команды `git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` и изменения файла `~/.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
" Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
" different version somewhere else.
" Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

выполняю команду `:PluginInstall` в Vim, возвращается ошибка:

**E492: Это не команда редактора: PluginInstall**

Comment: "изменения файла `.vimrc`" - а какие изменения то?

Comment: Добавил с git шаблонные плагины, скопировал просто.

Comment: привидите в вопросе вашу конфигурацию

Comment: отредактировал.

Comment: а какая версия vim?

Comment: Проблема решилась благодаря ответу ниже

Comment: Вообще-то это очень странно: вы не должны получать эту ошибку в случае не верно прописанного репозитория. Vundle должен установить все остальные плагины, а про этот написать что его установка завершилась ошибкой

Answer (score 1):

Закоментируйте строку:

```
Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
```